# Parse() Version Number with a groovy script?

Tags: javascript, parsing, groovy, sap-ariba, cloud-integration

I would like to ask if there's a way to parse a version number using a groovy script.

I extract from Ariba a payload, the issue comes with a specific field called `ItemNumber`.

At first it was working, but this month I started to retrieve a version instead of a float.

This is the part of the script that needs to be changed, but I can't find a way to do it.

```
if (ItemNumber?.trim()){
    list.ItemNumber = Double.parseDouble(ItemNumber.toString());
}
```

EDIT: This is the field I retrieve: `{ "ItemNumber": "4.4.5" }`.

I would like to get this: `{ "ItemNumber" : 4.4.5 }`.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Thank you,
Kostas

Comment: So what exactly does the item number look like? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: This is the field I retrieve: 
{ "ItemNumber": "4.4.5" }


I would like to get this:
{ "ItemNumber" : 4.4.5 }

Comment: "This is the field I retrieve: { "ItemNumber": "4.4.5" } I would like to get this: { "ItemNumber" : 4.4.5 }" - FYI... I think having multiple decimal points in the input may complicate your solution.  I deleted my answer because it won't work with that.

Comment: "This is the field I retrieve: { "ItemNumber": "4.4.5" }" - I think you should add that to the question as some solutions that folks will consider obvious might not work for that.

Comment: You can't have a numeric value with two decimal points. You're going to have to keep it as a string, or else break it up into some kind of multi-part value.'

Answer (score 0):

To parse a version number, you will need to tokenize the string. You should create a `Version` class to hold the version information. This can help when sorting a list of versions. After tokenizing, you can call the `Version` constructor, and pass the tokens as integers.

Once you have a `Version` object, you can access fields like `major`, `minor`, and `patch`.

```
class Version {
   int major
   Integer minor, patch
   @Override String toString() {
       return [major, minor, patch].findAll().join('.')
   }
}

def parseVersion(String versionString) {
    if (!versionString) return null
    int[] tokens = versionString.split(/\./).collect { it as int }
    return new Version(
        major: tokens[0],
        minor: tokens.length > 1 ? tokens[1] : null,
        patch: tokens.length > 2 ? tokens[2] : null,
    )
}

class Payload {
   String ItemNumber
}

Payload payload = new Payload(ItemNumber: "2.4")
Version version = parseVersion(payload.ItemNumber?.trim())
printf("Major version : %d%n", version.major)
printf("Minor version : %s%n", version.minor ?: "<UNSET>")
printf("Patch version : %s%n", version.patch ?: "<UNSET>")
printf("Full version  : %s%n", version)
```

In later versions of Groovy, you can call the `Versions` constructor like this:

```
new Version(major: tokens[0], minor: tokens?[1], patch: tokens?[2])
```

Comment: "In later versions of Groovy, you can call the Versions constructor like this" - How far back in Groovy versions do you have to go before that constructor invocation won't work?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I was using [v2.4.8](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_groovy_online.php)

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl, it works! but I can't adjust it in the groovy script, could kindly assist me on this?

import com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message;
import java.util.HashMap;
import groovy.json.*
def Message processData(Message message) {
def body = message.getBody(String.class);
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def list = jsonSlurper.parseText(body)
def ItemNumber = list.get("ItemNumber")
if (ItemNumber?.trim())
     {list.ItemNumber = Double.parseDouble(ItemNumber.toString());}
def jsonOP = JsonOutput.toJson(list)
message.setBody(jsonOP)
return message;}

Comment: @KonstantinosTektonidis, what's the expected result after transformation? and it sounds like a new question...